# Is $z^3 cot(z)$ analytic inside the unit circle ($z \in C$)?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-functions

I'd like to prove that $f(z)=z^3 \cot(z)$ is analytic in $0$. I know that $\cot(z)$ is not analytic in $\pm n \pi$ (and so in $0$), but this doesn't imply $z^3 \cot(z)$ being not analytic in $0$.

Everything I tried resulted in a very complicated combination of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions. I tried to show that $f(z)$ is continuous in $0$, that is differentiable in $0$, that the Cauchy-Reimann equation applies and that the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary part are continuous in $0$.

How to do that in a doable way?

From "Advanced engineering mathematics 10th edition - Kreyszig", "Problem Set 14.2", exercise 19, page 659. The answer is "yes", that is the Cauchy's integral theorem applies inside the unit circle, that is $f(z)$ is analytic there, and so the line integral around the unit circle is $0$.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Do you already know about Laurent series? If so, just look at the Laurent series of $\cot z$ on $0 < \lvert z\rvert < \pi$, and multiply it with $z^3$ to see that $z^3\cot z$ has a power series expansion about $0$.

Comment: No, the point is that chap. 13 and 14.1 and 14.2 address just: "CHAPTER 13 Complex Numbers and Functions, Complex Differentiation"; "CHAPTER 14 Complex Integration; 14.1 Line Integral in the Complex Plane; 14.2 Cauchy’s Integral Theorem"

Comment: Okay. You know that $z^3\cot z$ is holomorphic on $\{ z : 0 < \lvert z\rvert < \pi\}$, since it's a product of holomorphic functions there. Do you know that $\lim_{z\to 0} z\cot z = 1$?

Comment: yes, I know since $\lim_{z \to 0} \sin(z)/z=1$. This just proves that the limit exists, so?

Comment: So you multiply with another factor of $z^2$ to get a function that vanishes quadratically at $0$.

Comment: That proves that the function approaches 0 in any direction, so this implies the function being continuous, so the partial derivatives are also continuous, right? Then just elbow grease to prove that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$?

Comment: It immediately implies that the function is complex differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$. That suffices to conclude. If one insists, one can check that the partial derivatives are continuous at $0$, but generally, using partial derivatives and the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show a function is holomorphic is a last resort, only to be used if no good way can be found.

Answer (score 1):

From the Bernoulli numbers generating function :
$$ \frac{z}{e^z -1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!} \, z^n \text{ valid for } \vert z\vert <2\pi $$
It follows that for $\vert z\vert < \pi$
$$ z\cot z =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\,z^{2n} $$
Then your function $z\mapsto z^3\cot z$ has a convergent Taylor series inside the open disk $D(0,\pi)$ , thus it's analytic inside the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you. I just commented above that I'd like to show this without the use of series, because that's yet not being addressed at that point of the book.

Comment: You can expand your function about 0 : $z^3 \cot z = z^{2} + o(z^2)$. Then establish a zero residue of your function at 0, and the limit at this point (to prove continuity). The residue theorem gives a zero integral over any contour inside the open disk $D(0,2\pi)$. It remains to apply the Morera's theorem to conclude.